# what is the dimension of $ T^{-1}(X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V$ and $W$  be finite dimensional vector spaces, let   $ X $ be a subspace of $ W$  , and let $ T: V\longrightarrow W$  be a linear map. Prove that the dimension of $ T^{-1} (X) $  is at least **$\dim V- \dim W + \dim X $** . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $\dim T^{-1}(X)=\dim(\ker T)+\dim (X\cap \def\im{{\rm im\,}} \im T)$
2. $\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\im T)=\dim V$
3. $\dim (X\cap\im T)+\dim(X+\im T)=\dim X+\,\dim(\im T)$.

> For 1., choose a basis $x_1,..,x_k$ in $X\cap\im T$, and consider arbitrary preimages of them: $v_1,..,v_k$. Show that these are linearly independent, and that $\def\span{{\rm span}} \span(v_1,..,v_k)\oplus\ker T=T^{-1}(X)$.

Comment: Berci:thanks. I have another question. what is the most dimension $ T {−1} (x) $ ?

Comment: Ah, you mean $T^{-1}(X)$. Its max. is $\dim V$, e.g. if $T:V\to W$ is $v\mapsto 0$, then $T^{-1}(X)=V$.